# Undefined variable: errors (View: C:\wamp\www\laravel\myproject\resources\views\songs\create.blade.php)

Tags: php, error-handling, undefined, laravel-5

```
/*route.php*/
<?php
  $router->bind('songs', function($slug)
 {
    return App\Song::whereSlug($slug)->first();
 });
  $router->resource('songs','SongsController');
  Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
  });
?>
```

Getting undefined errors variable in `blade.php`

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the variable to your view create.balde.php that you are using their. here you actually return the array object.

use like this.

$song = App\Song::whereSlug($slug)->first();

return view('songs.create', compact('song'));

This error comes when you do not passed any variable and directly used in blade view file.

Comment: controler file:        public function create()
    {
        return view('songs.create');
    }
    public function store(CreateSongRequest $request,Song $song)
    {
        $song->create($request->all());
       //return redirect('songs');
        return redirect()->route('songs.index');
    }